# "Кроссовок" или "кроссовка"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, морфология

Единственное число от "кроссовки" - это "кроссовок" или "кроссовка"?

Comment: У Ожегова тоже "кроссовка".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Лопатина ответ *кроссовка*.

Answer (score 0):

У мальчика - туфель, у девочки - туфля; у мальчика - тапочек, у девочки - тапочка и т.д.:))
Конечно же, правильно - "кроссовка". Источники - словарь Ожегова и свои скромные познания в области родного языка.)

Answer (score 0):

По сути, кроссовки - это множественное число. Чтобы образовать единственное, нам нужно просто убрать характерное для множественного числа окончание (я про И). Получится кроссовка.

Кстати, можно тут ещё посмотреть: http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0

Answer (score 0):

крос-со́в-ка

Существительное, неодушевлённое, женский род, 1-е склонение (тип склонения 3*a по классификации А. А. Зализняка).

Корень: -кросс-; суффиксы: -ов-к; окончание: -а [Тихонов, 1996].

Произношение
МФА: [krɐˈsofkə]
Семантические свойства

Кроссовки
Значение
мн. ч. спортивная обувь для бега, ходьбы ◆   Вместо мокрых   [Гондольер] перед тем, как завернуть за угол дома напротив, оттолкнулся от стены ногой в кроссовке и, выровняв гондолу, запел ещё надрывнее, ― работал на туристов. Д. И. Рубина, «Высокая вода венецианцев», 1999 г. [НКРЯ]